# iOS. An instance of NSObject malloc memory to 16 bytes? What is the basis?

Tags: objective-c

```
+ (id)alloc {
    return _objc_rootAlloc(self);
}
=>
id
_objc_rootAlloc(Class cls)
{
    return callAlloc(cls, false/*checkNil*/, true/*allocWithZone*/);
}
=>
static ALWAYS_INLINE id
callAlloc(Class cls, bool checkNil, bool allocWithZone=false)
{
#if __OBJC2__
    if (slowpath(checkNil && !cls)) return nil;
    if (fastpath(!cls->ISA()->hasCustomAWZ())) {
        return _objc_rootAllocWithZone(cls, nil);
    }
#endif
    // No shortcuts available.
    if (allocWithZone) {
        return ((id(*)(id, SEL, struct _NSZone *))objc_msgSend)(cls, @selector(allocWithZone:), nil);
    }
    return ((id(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(cls, @selector(alloc));
}

=>
// Replaced by ObjectAlloc
+ (id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    return _objc_rootAllocWithZone(self, (malloc_zone_t *)zone);
}
=>
id
_objc_rootAllocWithZone(Class cls, malloc_zone_t *zone)
{
    id obj;

    if (fastpath(!zone)) {
        obj = class_createInstance(cls, 0);
    } else {
        obj = class_createInstanceFromZone(cls, 0, zone);
    }

    if (slowpath(!obj)) obj = _objc_callBadAllocHandler(cls);
    return obj;
}
=>
id class_createInstanceFromZone(Class cls, size_t extraBytes, void *z)
{
    OBJC_WARN_DEPRECATED;
    return (*_zoneAlloc)(cls, extraBytes, z);
}
=>
id (*_zoneAlloc)(Class, size_t, void *) = _class_createInstanceFromZone;
=>
id 
_class_createInstanceFromZone(Class cls, size_t extraBytes, void *zone)
{
    void *bytes;
    size_t size;

    // Can't create something for nothing
    if (!cls) return nil;

    // Allocate and initialize
    size = cls->alignedInstanceSize() + extraBytes;

    // CF requires all objects be at least 16 bytes.

    if (size < 16) size = 16;

    if (zone) {
        bytes = malloc_zone_calloc((malloc_zone_t *)zone, 1, size);
    } else {
        bytes = calloc(1, size);
    }

    return objc_constructInstance(cls, bytes);
}
```

I got the above function from the objc-class-old.mm file of objc4;
`// CF requires all objects be at least 16 bytes.`
From here I can get at least 16 bytes of malloc;

But,

```
=>
id class_createInstanceFromZone(Class cls, size_t extraBytes, void *z)
{
    OBJC_WARN_DEPRECATED;
    return (*_zoneAlloc)(cls, extraBytes, z);
}
```

The OBJC_WARN_DEPRECATED statement has been deprecated; therefore, can I not understand the 16bite problem in this order;
If I can follow this order, how do I understand this OBJC_WARN_DEPRECATED?

I look forward you to helping me resolve my doubts; thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That deprecated function is only called if zone != NULL. Normally, class_createInstance is called instead. Zones are deprecated.

Comment: id class_createInstance(Class cls, size_t extraBytes)
{
    return (*_alloc)(cls, extraBytes);
}
=>
id (*_alloc)(Class, size_t) = _class_createInstance;
=>
static id _class_createInstance(Class cls, size_t extraBytes)
{
    return _class_createInstanceFromZone (cls, extraBytes, nil);
}
=>                              Ah, yes, zone is always null, so it should be in this order, no problem at this time, thank you;